# Multiple HMT associations vs. a top level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have four interrelated models: restaurants, menus, sections, and dishes. The dishes `have_and_belong_to_many` sections and ultimately are at the very bottom of the association chain. In my app I often need to reference the restaurant of the dish multiple times.

I know to accomplish this I'd need create a cascade of HMT associations. My question is, is it ideal to setup a `belongs_to` relationship between a restaurant and dish to avoid the multiple queries or leave as is? As of now this just feels dirty (may just be me though).

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menus, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dishes, through: :menus
end

class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dishes, through: :sections

  belongs_to :restaurant
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu

  has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes
end

class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sections
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) you propose here seems reasonable to me given your use case. As always, the performance gains of denormalization must be weighed against the complexity it introduces, especially the need to write code to ensure that a the restaurant a dish belongs to is always the same restaurant its section's menu belongs to.

I guess my approach would be: **Retain the normalized data model until you have an actual performance problem that needs to be addressed.** Then you can consider denormalizing to address it.

While you are still have the cascade of HMTs, consider writing delegators to make the code as clean as if you had a direct restaurant-dish association. I'm thinking:

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :restaurant, to: :section
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :restaurant, to: :menu
end
```

Then you can do:

```
dish.restaurant
```

Comment: You're point on writing code to ensure that a the restaurant a dish belongs to the  same restaurant its section's menu belongs to has me starting to question my HABTM associations now.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that dishes HABTM sections. That's going to make the delegation I described fail, as it assumes a unique section per dish.

Comment: In this case am I stuck with denormalizing?

Comment: Given the associations you've set up, there is no guarantee that dishes have unique restaurants. They might have multiple sections that belong to multiple menus, which in turn have multiple restaurants. Give this, adding a `belongs_to :restaurant` to dishes would not be denormalization as it would introduce as *new* uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Wouldn't the issue you raised on having to set some sort of custom validation come back into play to ensure the dish belongs to the correct restaurant?